# Pivot query is returning all the values in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a requirement that I want to build a pivot query for my table which is shown in screen shot.

This is my table

[image]

I want to make the rows values into columns.

My try:

```
SELECT rno, NO,Description,CarNo,ID from 
             (
select row_number()over(partition by columnname order by rno)rno, columnname,value
                from mytable 
                group by rno, columnname,value
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for columnname in (NO,Description,CarNo,ID)
            ) p
```

Actual Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

```
NO      |   Description |   CradNo  |    ID
---------------------------------------------
Part1   |   desc1       |   Card1   |    1
Part2   |   desc2       |   Card1   |    1
```

Comment: my output is *different* from yours. Also what is 'CradNo' ?

Comment: as @PrabhatG says my output gives 2 rows. And of cause you cannot have Card1 on both rows when its only related to first row.

Comment: sorry i tried different query and pasted wrong one. the result i shown is the outcome of my query without row_number()

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE(columnname VARCHAR(20), value VARCHAR(10), rno INT)
INSERT INTO @mytable
VALUES
('ID', '1', 1),
('NO', 'Part1', 1),
('NO', 'Part2', 1),
('Description', 'desc1', 1),
('Description', 'desc2', 1),
('CarNo', 'car1', 1)

;WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY columnname Order BY rno, value) 
        FROM @mytable) SRC
PIVOT ( MAX(value) FOR columnName IN ([ID], [NO], [Description], [CarNo]) ) PVT
)
SELECT 
     ISNULL( T1.NO, T2.NO) NO
    , ISNULL( T1.Description, T2.Description) Description
    , ISNULL( T1.CarNo, T2.CarNo) CarNo
    , ISNULL( T1.ID, T2.ID) ID  
FROM CTE T1 OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE WHERE CTE.RN < T1.RN   ) T2
```

Result:

```
NO         Description CarNo      ID
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
Part1      desc1       car1       1
Part2      desc2       car1       1
```

Comment: Why not just write isnull(column,'car1') - Your making assumptions.. It might be true, but his logic is unreadable.

Comment: If any column is null then I fill it with the next row. It is base on the data. If you look at it, for empty values it fills from the other row.